# mysql JOIN, how is this interpreted?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

If I write a sql query for mysql and I just specify JOIN (no outer, inner, left, etc), what type of join does this default to?

For example:

SELECT count(*) FROM Students p JOIN Classes c ON p.studentId = c.studentId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most commonly, [INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join) is regarded as the default.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html), the word `inner` (or `cross`) is optional, indicating that the default is an inner join.

Comment: I looked for it, but I guess I must have missed it in my skimming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JOIN defaults to INNER JOIN