# MySQL aggregation function to sum the differences from row to row

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, aggregation

i've got this lil' mysql table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |  1240 |
|  2 |  1022 |
|  3 |   802 |
| .. |    .. |
+------+-----+
```

i'm searching for a sql-query summing up the difference between the rows:

difference of row 1 and 2 + difference of row 2 and 3 + ...

is that possibile with sql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!  Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       b.VALUE - a.VALUE difference 
FROM   mytable a 
       JOIN mytable b 
         ON b.id = a.id + 1
```

The idea is to join the table with itself offset by one row -- then you can do math with values that were originally on adjacent rows.

Comment: Probably worth making that an inner join so there's no confusion over the last record...

Comment: +1 simple and elegant. Make sure you take a look at @MattFellows 's comment

Comment: There is an implicit assumption here that ids are contiguous. If there are any gaps in your ids, e.g., due to deletions, this could trip you up.

Comment: What guarantees that next record in set has `id` whose value is larger by only 1? What if my auto_increment_offset is say 3, or if the WHERE clause filters out sequential ids?

Comment: @matt yes, it's already an inner join... mysql interprets unspecified joins as inner joins. ([discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807370/mysql-join-how-is-this-interpreted))

Comment: @awm - I actually missed that it was mysql - was in an mssql mindset, though now I'm not certain that the same is not true for mssql?

Comment: @RedFilter MySQL supports lag / lead so there's no need to do this. `select id, value - lag(value) over ( partition by id ) from my_table` is equivalent and you don't need the join. It removes the contiguous argument.